# Pass extra values to a signal in GTK+

Tags: c++, gtk

How can I pass extra values to a signal in GTK+?

For example:

```
void btnclicked(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data, const char *str)
{
    std::cout << str;
}

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(btnclicked), NULL, "extra string");
```

I can't use C++0x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what that `data` parameter is for:

```
void btnclicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer data)
{
    const char *str = (const char *)data;
    std::cout << str;
}

g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(btnclicked), "extra string");
```

There are better ways in C++ if you use Gtkmm, that involve `sigc`, but since you're using GTK's C API you'll have to do it the C way.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the string as data to `g_signal_connect(instance, detailed_signal, c_handler, data)` and cast in your handler.

```
void btnclicked(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    std::cout << (const char*)data;
}

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(btnclicked), "extra string");
```